# Can jQuery or javascript determine date from a text string, then compare two dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, comparison

I'm dealing with an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="post-info">
    <span class="date published time" title="2013-10-01T13:49:12+00:00">October 1st, 2013</span>
    <p>Info about person.</p>
    <p>Special notice that only displays if the date is September 27th, 2013 or later.</p>
</div>
```

Putting the title of the span into a variable, I used `substr()` to extract the part that reads like "YYYY-MM-DD".

But isn't it in the variable as a text string? How can I then convert this text string into a date object, and then compare that to 2013-09-27 to execute a block of code only if the date in the span title is the 27th or newer?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 2):

Convert the text into a Date object

```
var theDateString = '2013-10-01';  // the date you got using the substr() function
if (new Date(theDateString) >= new Date('2013-09-27')) {
    // your code to run if the date is greater than or equal to 2013-09-27
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class of hidden to the information to be shown after said date and add css to hide it

```
<p class="hidden">Special notice that only displays if the date is September 27th, 2013 or later.</p>

<style>        
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Get the element's title and parse it into a date.

```
var date = new Date($(".date.published.time").prop("title"));
```

Then compare the date to September, 27

```
var compare = new Date("2013", "8", "27");
```

If the date is greater that the 27th remove the class of hidden from the information

```
if (compare < date){
    $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

[Here is a Fiddle for it.](http://jsfiddle.net/bHgW7/2/)